# The document “UIViewController.h” could not be saved. You don’t have permission

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have accidentally made changes to the uiviewcontroller class. I did not mean to make these changes.

I have tried to find the class and remove the code. I can't do this as I don't have permissioj

I get this message when building the project.

The document 'UiViewController could not be saved.

I would like to get rid of the changes made to this file but I can't seem to do that as I don't have permission.

Comment: did you restart xcode or your mac? did it make any difference?

Comment: I actually cannot close xcode or restart my mac because of this file

Comment: You can force quit xcode by holding option when you right click on xcode in the dock.

Comment: I had this issue long time back, and the only way I resolved it, was to delete and reinstall Xcode (I'm sure there's a better way to do it, but this was just simpler). If you have time machine backups, probably you could try restoring to an earlier state from it.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't think about just trying to undo the changes!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually to just undo the changes by pressing 'cmd+z'.